# How to send a header using a HTTP request through a cURL call?

Tags: curl, http-headers

I wish to send a header to my Apache server on a Linux box.  How can I achieve this via a cURL call?

Comment: There is a good way to learn how to use curl for http requests by examples. Download the newest version of Postman, make any http request configuration as you wish at user interface level (post, put, get.. for instance, with headers and json body ) and then click in "generate code" and choose "curl" option. It gives you the equivalent command line.

Answer (score 907, accepted):

**GET:**

*with JSON:*

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://hostname/resource
```

*with XML:*

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET http://hostname/resource
```

**POST:**

*For posting data:*

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://hostname/resource
```

*For file upload:*

```
curl --form "fileupload=@filename.txt" http://hostname/resource
```

*RESTful HTTP Post:*

```
curl -X POST -d @filename http://hostname/resource
```

*For logging into a site (auth):*

```
curl -d "username=admin&password=admin&submit=Login" --dump-header headers http://localhost/Login
curl -L -b headers http://localhost/
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14978657/8285811)

Comment: what is meant by @filename for the RESTful post?  are you POSTing a file to a REST server?  that seems odd to me

Comment: For people arriving later who might be wondering the same thing... @ notation is a way of reading the data to send to the server from a file, rather than inline-ing it into the curl request. You don't POST a file per se, you're POSTing the contents of the file as the body of your POST request.

Comment: More detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978411/http-post-and-get-using-curl-in-linux/14978657 :)

Comment: If I understand the usage of headers correctly: header `Accept` is meant for the *client* (asking/requesting), who wishes to have this, BUT the Header `Content-Type` is only the servers *answer* nothing more, it is not mistakenly the wish of the client: *“I want this type of content”* . Right? So for **GET**  `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://hostname/resource` should be it. Am I wrong? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type «In responses, a `Content-Type` header tells the client what the content type of the returned content actually is.»

Comment: @andreas.naturwiki, again not to be confused. From MDN, «In responses...» means `Content-Type` at the response. Not the request. `Content-Type` will always refer to type of data transmitted between two parties. If it is on request header, it means the client says 'Yeah I'm sending you data type `application/json`' to the server. If it is on response, it means the server says 'Now I'm sending you data type `text/plain`' to the client.

Comment: @andreas.naturwiki Content-Type is what you're sending in the body of the request and Accept is what you want in the body of the response. Server responds with Content-Type, which can be different from your Accept.

Comment: If you're just going to copy someone's code, at least link the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14978657/8285811).

Answer (score 2319):

[`man curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
   -H/--header <header>
          (HTTP)  Extra header to use when getting a web page. You may specify
          any number of extra headers. Note that if you should  add  a  custom
          header that has the same name as one of the internal ones curl would
          use, your externally set header will be used instead of the internal
          one.  This  allows  you  to make even trickier stuff than curl would
          normally do. You should not replace internally set  headers  without
          knowing  perfectly well what you're doing. Remove an internal header
          by giving a replacement without content on the  right  side  of  the
          colon, as in: -H "Host:".

          curl  will  make sure that each header you add/replace get sent with
          the proper end of line marker, you should thus not  add  that  as  a
          part  of the header content: do not add newlines or carriage returns
          they will only mess things up for you.

          See also the -A/--user-agent and -e/--referer options.

          This option can be used multiple times to add/replace/remove  multi-
          ple headers.
```

## Example 1: Single Header

```
curl --header "X-MyHeader: 123" www.google.com
```

## Example 2: Multiple Headers

```
curl --header "Accept: text/javascript" --header "X-Test: hello" -v www.google.com
```

You can see the request that curl sent by adding the `-v` option.

Comment: If you want to send multiple headers use more than one --header, it is ok, curl will parse each as a different header. There is no way to separate headers inside the same --header parameter. example: curl --header "Accept: javascript" --header "test: hello" -v www.google.com

Comment: If people want examples I'll just leave this here: http://bropages.org/

Comment: man pages (on OSX, at least) now DO include an example:
Example:
# curl -H "X-First-Name: Joe" http://192.168.0.1/

Comment: @MartinKonicek and others: I HIGHLY recommend the tldr utiltiy (brew, etc install tldr).  Its only examples. eg "- Send a request with an extra header, using a custom HTTP method:
    curl -H 'X-My-Header: 123' -X PUT http://example.com"

Comment: This post should be the accepted answer. The currently accepted answer, however correct, only answers the OPs question implicitly.

Comment: For whatever reason, this works for me only if I remove the space after the colon.

Comment: Funny how this answer is basically "RTFM" haha

Answer (score 294):

In *PHP*:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('HeaderName:HeaderValue'));
```

or you can set multiple:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('HeaderName:HeaderValue', 'HeaderName2:HeaderValue2'));
```

Comment: @James it works fine in some cases, but in others CURL sends an additional header "Expect: 100-continue" - any idea on how to remove it ?

Comment: @coding_idiot: You can pass "Expect:" in the array of header values to disable it. Ex.: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('HeaderName: HeaderValue', 'Expect:'));

Comment: OP didn't say anything about PHP thought

Comment: Header name is upper cased with underscores, and HTTP_ is prefixed. For example, "protection-token" becomes "HTTP_PROTECTION_TOKEN".

Comment: @hanshenrik That's true, but OP didn't say anything about the command line either. In fact, the question should have been put on hold for being unclear. Today a newbie wouldn't get away with such a sloppy question.

Answer (score 63):

Use [`-H or --header`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H).

Man page: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H

Comment: -H option can be used in command prompt, like: curl -H "pwd:123" http://localhost/test.php

Comment: Thanks. Short, concise and covered by link to doc. However the link is obsolete already, the new one now is https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H

Answer (score 50):

GET (multiple parameters):

```
curl -X  GET "http://localhost:3000/action?result1=gh&result2=ghk"
```

or

```
curl --request  GET "http://localhost:3000/action?result1=gh&result2=ghk"
```

or

```
curl  "http://localhost:3000/action?result1=gh&result2=ghk"
```

or

```
curl -i -H "Application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json"  "http://localhost:3000/action?result1=gh&result2=ghk"
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt realize the mandatory quotes for this kind of url.

Answer (score 28):

You can also send multiple headers, data (JSON for example), and specify Call method (POST,GET) into a single CUrl call like this:

```
curl -X POST(Get or whatever) \
  http://your_url.com/api/endpoint \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'header-element1: header-data1' \
  -H 'header-element2: header-data2' \
```

......more headers................

```
  -d '{
  "JsonExArray": [
    {
      "json_prop": "1",
    },
    {
      "json_prop": "2",
    }
  ]
}'
```

Comment: I think it used in bash, Not in cmd. Am I right ? Do let me know sir.

Comment: Yeah its bash then.

Answer (score 28):

I use Postman.

Execute whatever call you want to do. Then, postman provides a handy tool to show the curl code .

Run it in the terminal.
 [image]

[image]

Comment: This is a good hack to speed things up but be careful of escaping the single quotes or double quotes if you are using shell script on windows as shell script has it's own formatting requirements

Comment: While postman is nice tool but when you dont have a graphical environment like in Kubernetes pods it is useless. Learn curl and you can always test rest.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433083/8285811) for a visual guide for how to generate this.

Answer (score 10):

I've switched from curl to [Httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie); the syntax looks like:

```
http http://myurl HeaderName:value
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you want send your **custom headers**, you can do it this way:

```
curl -v -H @{'custom_header'='custom_header_value'} http://localhost:3000/action?result1=gh&result2=ghk
```

Comment: Doesn't that try to read headers from a file named `{'custom_header'='custom_header_value'}`?

Answer (score 6):

In **anaconda** envirement through **windows** the commands should be: 
GET, for ex:

```
curl.exe http://127.0.0.1:5000/books
```

Post or Patch the data for ex:

```
curl.exe http://127.0.0.1:5000/books/8 -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"rating\":\"2\"}'
```

PS: Add backslash for json data to avoid this type of error => `Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

and use `curl.exe` instead of `curl` only to avoid this problem:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type: application/json" value of type
"System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:48
+ ... 0.1:5000/books/8 -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\" ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with the original posted question.

Comment: @MarkHu  It responses to the question headline, not the question body :). The is many questions similar to the question headline so they will take adv of my answer and I was one of them so once I find the answer I shared it.

Comment: It's powershell Curl function - not curl.exe

Answer (score 3):

Here are the some curl commands for most common http methods.

Domain Object considered here is

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document
@Validated
public class Movie {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private Integer year;
    @NotNull
    private List<String> cast;
    private LocalDate release_date;
}
```

### POST-CREATE-MOVIE

```
curl -i \
-d '{"id":1, "name": "Dhoom", "year":2004,"cast":["John Abraham", "Abhishek Bachan"],"release_date": "2004-06-15"}' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST http://localhost:8080/v1/movies
```

### GET-ALL-MOVIES

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/v1/movies
```

### GET-MOVIE-BY-ID

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/v1/movies/1
```

### PUT-UPDATE-MOVIE

```
curl -i \
-d '{"id":1, "name": "Dhoom", "year":2005,"cast":["John Abhraham", "Abhishek Bachhan", "Uday Chopra", "Isha Deol"],"release_date": "2005-03-25"}' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X PUT http://localhost:8080/v1/movies/1
```

### DELETE-MOVIE

```
curl -i -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/v1/movies/1
```