# Need IPv6 Traffic Generator

Tags: c++, networking, ipv6

I am looking for the tool to generator IPv6 Traffic. It should allow me to give all its header value manually by me.

It would be great if source code is available.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe both [mgen](http://cs.itd.nrl.navy.mil/work/mgen/index.php) and [iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) supports IPv6. Both are open source.

Answer (score 1):

As bortzmeyer notes in the comments to another answer, the tool you want for controlling all the header values manually is Scapy.  Get it here:  http://hg.secdev.org/scapy/

Answer (score 0):

Curl should do what you want to.  You can get it here : http://curl.haxx.se/

It's open source so the code will be available for you to inspect and it supports IPv6

curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml" ... --ipv6 http://www.example.com/ should do exactly what the OP wants to do.

curl -h gives a complete list of the command line options

Comment: I don't see how libcurl could support the requirments of the OP, specially setting the headers. For that, he would need a much lower-level tool like Scapy.

Comment: @bortzmeyer,

You are dam right. But the Lib is also usefull for us now for a while in one of our project. But my question related to tool not lib.

Comment: Curl comes with an command line executable 'curl'.  As such it is a tool as we ll as a lib.  The -H option of the curl tool allows you to pass a custom header to the server.  I suggest you run curl -h to get a listing of all the options available to you.

Comment: Quick followup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call