# Perl: Value of response code in HTTP::Request

Tags: perl, http, request

So, I am writing a code to get a document from the internet. The document size is around 200 KB. This is the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = "SOME URL";
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $res = $ua->request($req);

if($res->is_success){
   print $res->content ."\n";
}
else{
  print "Error: " . $res->status_line;
}
```

Now, the only problem is I can't mention what the URL is.

However, the output is: "Error: 500 read timeout". When I checked the link externally, the data is being downloaded in under 5 seconds.

I even changed the timeout to 1000s, but it still didn't work.  How should I go about finding more information related to the response?  The size of the file (around 200KB) is also not big enough to warrant a read timeout.  The server is also not a busy one, didn't give a problem whenever I checked the link on the browser.

Thanks.

Comment: No proxy involved. 
Tried the link using curl, and the message was: (52) empty reply from server. 
So, how do i know if the data is being sent but not getting delivered.
Or, the server is closing the connection prematurely. 
In either case, why is the status as "500 read timeout" ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure webserver is not configured to drop requests from scripts in this case perl.

Answer (score 0):

When network applications give you trouble, [debug using Wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118415#2118994).

Answer (score 0):

The web server (Apache/nginx) may have a backend app written on PHP/Python/whatever. Probably that backend isn't answering anything, so the web server stop waiting (reach timeout) and answer to you on the http request a [5xx (internal server) error](https://httpstatusdogs.com/500-internal-server-error).

One great tool for testing is `curl` with `-v`:

```
curl --verbose --head "SOME URL"
```

- `--head` to fetch only http response header.
- If from same host on a browser everything is OK there is something in your http request header that make the difference. You can see con browser dev tool what you are sending and add them [to curl with `-H, --header <header>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356714/4970442). Adjusting curl parameters web server can't tell if the received http req is from a web browser, a script, or anything else (protocols magic!).
- Use `-s` (silent) and `2>&1` to [send curl output through pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427484/4970442) to less/head/tail.