# cURL PHP code for Facebook

Tags: php, curl

All,

Currently I have a Facebook page that gets updated every few minutes using the cURL command. The command is :

`curl.exe -kF "access_token=XXX" -F "message=YYY" https://graph.facebook.com/<appID>/feed`

How can I programmatically implement the `-k` and `-F` in PHP?

[edit-05/24 - 15:59EST]:

-k flag:  Allow connections to SSL sites without certs (H)
-F: -F/--form  Specify HTTP multipart POST data (H)

I am not sure if `message` and `access_token` should be passed as POST fields. Can anyone please guide me on this?

I am getting the error:
`{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 1.8800586791358e 14"
}}* Connection #0 to host graph.facebook.com left intact`

Comment: You may get more responses if you outline what they do exactly

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call

Comment: here is how you use curl in php http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the function [curl_setopt()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

View the documentation of `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Can you please help me out with the error above?