# Change the nature of a URL request at IMDB

Tags: r, plyr, rvest

I am trying to get data from IMDB with

```
page <- read_html("URL_of_Movie")
```

The output is always in German. However, I need the data content to be in its original form in English. Although my settings are set to "English"

I saw others Questions here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009090/imdb-scraping-issue)

```
curl -H "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.8,de-de;q=0.5,de;q=0.3" http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076306/
```

which shows how to use curl function for english but I don't know how to integrate this into my R code

Answer (score 1):

Needed to include the GET Function and the correct Syntax for the language request

```
page <- read_html(GET(
  "https://www.imdb.com/list/ls020643534/?sort=list_order,asc&st_dt=&mode=detail&page=1&title_type=movie&ref_=ttls_ref_typ",
  add_headers("Accept-Language" = "en-US")))
```