# WSSE auth in Symfony2, how to generate proper headers?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm following the [custom authentication provider](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) cookbook of Symfony 2 but i have no idea how to generate a login form or something with the proper required WSSE headers, so i can pass this to my custom user provider.

Any docs or tutorials on this? Maybe some examples? The documentation lacks such info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you should not use a login form to send WSSE headers to your server: a login form will send an HTTP POST request (with POST parameters), but will not modify the HTTP headers, as expected by an WSSE connection.

I am using WSSE with javascript and/or some client like Android applications.

For testing, I use curl in command line, adding wsse-headers in the request.

Here is [another question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call) which should help you to manipulate curl, and an [helpful javascript wsse generator](http://www.teria.com/~koseki/tools/wssegen/).

Answer (score 1):

Hee is an example of PHP Client WSSE generator with Symfony

```
function hashPassword($password, $salt)
{
    $salted = $password . '{' . $salt . '}';
    $digest = hash('sha512', $salted, true);

    //5000 iterations: the sysmfony default iterations
    for ($i = 1; $i < 5000; $i++) {
        $digest = hash('sha512', $digest . $salted, true);
    }

    return base64_encode($digest);
}

function wsse_header($username, $hashedPassword)
{
    $nonce = hash_hmac('sha512', uniqid(null, true), uniqid(), true);
    $created = new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('UTC'));
    $created = $created->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
    $digest = hash('sha512', $nonce . $created . $hashedPassword, true);

    return sprintf(
            'X-WSSE: UsernameToken Username="%s", PasswordDigest="%s", Nonce="%s", Created="%s"',
            $username, base64_encode($digest), base64_encode($nonce), $created
    );
}



echo wsse_header('someUsername',
                 hashPassword('somePassword', 'someSalt'));
```

You can adapt this example to other clients (Android, Ios, Javascript,...)