# Upload a file with php curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Sending the wrong mime-type. the file type "video/mp4" but "application / octet-stream" as the sending. I want to send "video/mp4".
Curl option($file = real path)

```
$post = array('videoupload'=>'1','input_1'=>"@$file");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,(string)filesize($file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE,fopen($file,'r'));
```

Http debugger Out

> > ------------------------------94a50e65d9fe Content-Disposition: form-data; name="videoupload"
>
> 1
>   ------------------------------94a50e65d9fe Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input_1"; filename="1.mp4" Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream

I've tried it

```
$post = array('videoupload'=>'1','input_1'=>"@$file;type=video/mp4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,(string)filesize($file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE,fopen($file,'r'));
```

curl_error out:

> failed creating formpost data

Comment: Don't you want `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call

Comment: header is correct(Content-Type: multipart/form-data"). remote server checking file mime-type($_FILES['input_1']["type"]).

Comment: You might want to update the question to be more clear.  Anyway, you never want to trust `$_FILES[..]['type']` - Try and use something like [`finfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) if you need to do this.

Comment: Http Debugger(Google Chrome):Content-type:multipart/form-data;
http://tny.cz/d4a8fba5
Http Debugger(Curl): Content-type:multipart/form-data; http://tny.cz/acd09926

Comment: I solved the problem. The problem is the windows. Php curl library not support in windows os. "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" Must define to header.

Comment: Is this post ever going to help anyone else?  Maybe OP can update the question and better explain the solution? I still don't even know I understand the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

try adding CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER in curl_setopt  like that

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: video/mp4'));
```

Comment: header is correct(Content-Type: multipart/form-data"). Because not only the video. Data is available.

Comment: Ok, but http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php says, `In order to enable this module on a Windows environment, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll must be present in your PATH. You don't need libcurl.dll from the cURL site.`. Is really we need curl on windows to run php-curl ?

Comment: But yes it can be possible if header content-type have different behavior on windows.

Comment: I solved the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622814/upload-a-file-with-php-curl/15623134?noredirect=1#comment22168318_15622814