# curl doesn't get 302 but 200

Tags: php, curl

I am using `curl` to retrieve content from a website, but the http code retrieved by curl is 200 and the content is empty. When I used this on firefox, I see a 302 redirection. I have already addes this line:

```
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

When I used the command line, I get the same result:

```
curl -I -L http://www.caudalie.fr
```

In Firefox, the final location will be `http://fr.caudalie.com/` but curl never gets this.
Have you an idea?

Comment: I get a 401 on that address.

Comment: show ur full curl php code

Comment: also it may not be a header redirect?  http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Redirects_work_in_browser_but_no

Comment: It is a header redirect. Firebug told me so.

Comment: Setting `FOLLOWLOCATION` to `true` will make curl to follow redirects until a non-redirect header. If you need that 3XX header, set it to false.

Comment: It is some server setting. It only redirects if it gets the `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: Followlocation doesn't change anything. Another ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried some different request headers, starting from the headers Firefox sent. The minimum doesnt work:

```
bf@desktop-bf:~$ telnet www.caudalie.fr 80
Trying 178.16.174.50...
Connected to www.caudalie.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.caudalie.fr
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 07:23:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
```

I got a redirect if I give a language:

```
bf@desktop-bf:~$ telnet www.caudalie.fr 80
Trying 178.16.174.50...
Connected to www.caudalie.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.caudalie.fr
Accept-Language: nl,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 07:23:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Location: http://fr.caudalie.com/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
```

So, add a `Accept-Language` header and you should be OK. In PHP, that would be:

```
curl_setopt($http,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept-Language: nl,en;q=0.7;en-us;q=0.3'));
```

See also here: [How to send a header using a HTTP request through a curl call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call)

Comment: I hope you didn't copy/paste my PHP code, because there is an error in it.

Comment: i have taken only the last line, and i have correct the http with my variable.