# How to simulate HTTP navigation

Tags: php, http, redirect, curl, header

I'm working in two projects.

Project A
Project B

Both are hosted in the same server. Thee only difference is that Project B has been added to a Phone Carrier's gateway, so it can display extra HTTP HEADERS added by the Phone Carrier.

When the phone is redirected from Project A to navigate directly on Project B, PHP is able to display all headers, even those headers added by the carrier.

When the phone navigating on Project A and curl to Project B, all the headers added by the carrier are missing.

[image: Flow]
Is there any way to simulate HTTP navigation without redirecting the user to Project B?

Why headers are missing?

Any? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the appropriate headers with curl as answered in this question:

[How to send a header using a HTTP request through a curl call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call)

Comment: Actually, I'm not trying to set any extra header from Project A to Project B. What I'm trying to do is to get exactly the same information (headers) in both cases; When cellphone navigate on Project B and when I do a curl from Project A to Project B.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something that the Project B is looking for to determine that you came from A?
E.g. check that you have the same cookies in the requests.  That you X-Referer and User-Agent are the same etc etc

Comment: Ok, I'll check it and let you know if I find out what's going on.