# How to call cURL without using server-side cache?

Tags: linux, bash, caching, curl, memcached

Is there a way to tell cURL command not to use server's side cache?
e.g; I have this curl command:

`curl -v www.example.com`

How can I ask curl to send a fresh request to not use the cache?

**Note**: I am looking for an executable command in the terminal.

Comment: What makes you think curl is caching the request?

Comment: I am talking about server side caching; suppose the site is using `memcache`

Comment: If you have access to the server you could implement a custom parameter that bypassed the cache, otherwise, no.

Comment: Code your application on the server-side to accept an argument to bypass the cache.

Comment: @AlexK.  can I pass the parameter using `-d` option? can you provide an example please?

Comment: I think what Alex is talking about is sending a parameter in the URL, say `http://www.example.com/?caching=off` You could also send a custom header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call But of course your server side application has to understand those commands and act on them by turning the caching off. If anyone could disable a remote site's caching mechanisms, it would be a gaping security hole

Answer (score 201, accepted):

I know this is an older question, but I wanted to post an answer for users with the same question:

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' http://www.example.com
```

This curl command servers in its header request to return non-cached data from the web server.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This worked great for me and it answers the question.

Comment: I agree with Monkpit. This works great and should be accepted as the answer.

Comment: This helps sometimes, but is not guaranteed to work. The server or proxies in the middle can ignore the `no-cache` request.

Comment: @wisbucky Then we put the blame on whoever manage that server.

Answer (score 99):

The `-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'` argument is not guaranteed to work because the remote server or any proxy layers in between can ignore it. If it doesn't work, you can do it the old-fashioned way, by adding a unique querystring parameter. Usually, the servers/proxies will think it's a unique URL and not use the cache.

```
curl "http://www.example.com?foo123"
```

You have to use a different querystring value every time, though. Otherwise, the server/proxies will match the cache again. To automatically generate a different querystring parameter every time, you can use `date +%s`, which will return the seconds since epoch.

```
curl "http://www.example.com?$(date +%s)"
```

Comment: Trying to use this with GitHub's raw files but no luck :(

Comment: Yeah it does not work with GitHub's raw files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55615178/5705559

Answer (score 10):

Neither `-H 'Pragma: no-cache'` nor `-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'` helped me.  In browser with "cmd+shift+r" (full reload) I was seeing a new version than the output of `curl` in terminal.

### How to debug for yourself

To get the exact same result, I went to browser > F12 (Dev Tools) > Network/Requests > Right-click on the request > "Copy as cURL" and got the **equivalent cURL** command to the browser's call.

Then, I pasted that in the terminal and started removing the params one by one, until I found that surprisingly `--compressed` was making a difference in my case. (Calling CloudFront AWS)

Comment: This is most likely because of the vary header. Maybe there was no cached version for the compressed request, else it would have behaved the same.

Answer (score 2):

You could try following ways to force not to keep Cache when `curl`.

Note: The server may or may not be configured to respect the `Cache-Control` header. Therefore, whether this method will work is dependent on the server or website we’re sending the `HTTP` request to.

**curl command with the Cache-Control header**

```
$ curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store' http://www.example.com
```

**Adding the Pragma HTTP Header**

```
$ curl -H 'Pragma: no-cache' http://www.example.com
```

**Finally, the most common way: bypass the cache by changing the URL**

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store' http://www.example.com?$(date +%s)
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is I should use single quotes in a query string.

My code

```
if (event.queryStringParameters && event.queryStringParameters['Name']) {
    responseMessage = 'Hello, ' + event.queryStringParameters['Name'] + '!';
  }
```

My requests

```
curl https://cssrq1srud.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/serverless_lambda_stage/hello?Name=Terraform
```

returns `zsh: no matches found`

```
curl 'https://cssrq1srud.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/serverless_lambda_stage/hello?Name=Terraform'
```

returns `{"message":"Hello, Terraform!"}`

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me:

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' http://www.example.com
```

but this ended up doing the trick:

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' http://www.example.com&someFakeParam=$RANDOM
```

the **&someFakeParam=$RANDOM** makes the URL unique each time and bypasses caching.