# Github not update `raw` after commit

Tags: git, github

Updated: Seem it has about 5 minutes to update raw. I will close my question at here.

I have a problem with Github.

I want to get the file as `raw` format.

I add new commit and my file is updated.

Look like this:

[image]

I add `JUST` keyword in variable `tech`.

[image]

When I click `raw`. It keeps the previous version.

Look like this:

[image]

Have any method to get `raw` version of the file was commit.

Comment: I find my problem: Seem it has about 5 minutes to update raw. I will close my question at here.

Comment: Yeah this messes with some of my programs but what can you do. At least I know its not just me!

Comment: If accept the answer (in case it was helpful), you will mark your question as solved.

Comment: Is there a way to force a cache clear from GitHub?

Answer (score 87):

GitHub serves "raw" pages with `Cache-Control: max-age=300`.  That's specified in seconds, meaning the pages are intended to be cached for 5 minutes.

You can see this if you open the Developer Tools in your web browser of choice before clicking the "Raw" button on GitHub.