# Django Rest Framework custom authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

[Django rest framework: Custom Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication)

I want to use custom authentication in my Django app but cannot find how to apply this. The example given in the documentation is clear to me but they did not mention where to create this new class and how to use this.

Answer (score 47):

**How to implement a custom authentication scheme in DRF?**

To implement a custom authentication scheme, we need to subclass the DRF's `BaseAuthentication` class and override the `.authenticate(self, request)` method.

The method should return a two-tuple of `(user, auth)` if authentication succeeds, or `None` otherwise. In some circumstances, we may raise an `AuthenticationFailed` exception from the `.authenticate()` method.

**Example (from [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#example)):**

Lets say we want to authenticate any incoming request as the user given by the `username` in a custom request header named `'X_USERNAME'`.

**Step-1: Create the Custom authentication class**

To do that, we will create an `authentication.py` file in `my_app`.

```
# my_app/authentication.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class ExampleAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.META.get('X_USERNAME') # get the username request header
        if not username: # no username passed in request headers
            return None # authentication did not succeed

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username) # get the user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user') # raise exception if user does not exist 

        return (user, None) # authentication successful
```

**Step-2: Specify the custom authentication class**

After creating the custom authentication class, we need to define this authentication class in our DRF settings. Doing this, all the requests will be authenticated based on this authentication scheme.

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (       
    'my_app.authentication.ExampleAuthentication', # custom authentication class
    ...
),
```

**Note:** If you want to use this custom authentication class on **per-view basis or per-viewset basis** and not on global level, you can define this authentication class explicitly in your views.

```
class MyView(APIView):

    authentication_classes = [ExampleAuthentication,] # specify this authentication class in your view

    ...
```

Comment: can you please give an example on  how to use this using curl?

Comment: @momokjaaaaa Check this SO link for sending headers in a POST request.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call

Comment: Where do we check for password? In the example they give, anyone can login which just makes it all more confusing.

Answer (score 16):

Below is a simple example that can be used to achieve a custom authentication. To access the endpoint you have to pass the username&password on the POST data.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^stuff/', views.MyView.as_view()),
    ...
]
```

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView    
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework import authentication
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication


class ExampleAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        # Get the username and password
        username = request.data.get('username', None)
        password = request.data.get('password', None)

        if not username or not password:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('No credentials provided.'))

        credentials = {
            get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD: username,
            'password': password
        }

        user = authenticate(**credentials)

        if user is None:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('Invalid username/password.'))

        if not user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('User inactive or deleted.'))

    return (user, None)  # authentication successful


class MyView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, ExampleAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):    
        content = {
            'user': unicode(request.user),
            'auth': unicode(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
```

**Curl**

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8000/stuff/ -d 'username=my_username&password=my_password'
```

Comment: Why is the second returned parameter(auth) None?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following way

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework import status, generics

 class UserLogin(generics.CreateAPIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.data['email']
        if email is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Email not informed'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            if not user.check_password(request.data['password']):
                return Response({'error': 'Email ou senha incorreto'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
            jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
            payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
            token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
            return Response({"token": token, "user":UserSessionSerializerAuth(user,
                        context={'request': request}).data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'error': 'User not found'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Why override a create apiview for such a task

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar situation where I had to implement a custom authentication class. Request coming to the rest endpoint were using `basic auth` but the username weren't a django user. Requests were authnticated against username and password configured in `settings.py`. Here's my implementation:

**- Created custom authentication class**

```
# myapp/api/auth.py

"""Custom authentication module"""

import base64
import binascii

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.six import text_type
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication
from rest_framework import HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING, exceptions


class CustomAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    """
    Custom authentication class.
    It will authenticate any incoming request
    as the user given by the username in a
    custom request header.
    """

    def authenticate(self, request):
        """
        Returns a `User` if a correct username and password have been supplied
        using HTTP Basic authentication.  Otherwise returns `None`.
        """

        # Gets authorization from request header
        # and checks different possibility of
        # invalid header.
        # ======================================

        auth = self.get_authorization_header(request).split()

        if not auth or auth[0].lower() != b"basic":
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_("Invalid header!"))

        if len(auth) == 1:
            msg = _("Invalid basic header. No credentials provided.")
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        elif len(auth) > 2:
            msg = _(
                "Invalid basic header. Credentials string should not contain spaces."
            )
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        try:
            auth_parts = (
                base64.b64decode(auth[1]).decode(HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING).partition(":")
            )
        except (TypeError, UnicodeDecodeError, binascii.Error):
            msg = _("Invalid basic header. Credentials not correctly base64 encoded.")
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        # parses username and password.
        userid, password = auth_parts[0], auth_parts[2]

        if userid != settings.FERRATUM_CALLBACK_USERNAME:
            msg = _("Invalid basic header. Username is incorrect!")
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        if password != settings.FERRATUM_CALLBACK_PASSWORD:
            msg = _("Invalid basic header. Password is incorrect!")
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        # An user object is expected to be returned
        # in case of successful authentication. Therefore
        # a user object is returned with the give username
        # in the header. This user doesn't exists in the
        # django user User model.
        # ===============================================

        user = {
            "username": userid,
            "password": "",
            "email": "",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "company": "",
        }

        return (user, None)

    @staticmethod
    def get_authorization_header(request):
        """
        Return request's 'Authorization:' header, as a bytestring.

        Hide some test client ickyness where the header can be unicode.
        """

        auth = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION", b"")
        if isinstance(auth, text_type):
            # Work around django test client oddness
            auth = auth.encode(HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING)
        return auth
```

**- Added it in DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS**

```
# myapp/settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "mozilla_django_oidc.contrib.drf.OIDCAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
        "users.auth.SaveriumTokenAuthentication",
        "api.auth.CustomAuthentication"
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
}
```

**- Used the custom authentication in view**

```
# myapp/api/view/api_view.py

from api.auth import CustomAuthentication


class UpdateStatus(APIView):
    """
    It updates application status
    """
    
    # Custom authentication scheme.
    authentication_classes = [CustomAuthentication]

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Callback comes as a POST request
        with data in JSON format.
        """

        data = self.request.data
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the folder that holds your api files, create another file to hold your custom authentication class, such as `authentication.py`. Then in your settings, under [DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#api-policy-settings), point to your custom authentication class.