# Calling curl URL in android

Tags: android, curl

Let me directly come to the point.

I have one curl url like below

```
curl https://api.start.payfort.com/tokens/ \
   -u test_open_k_1741a9b51afbb3a986f2: \
   -d "number=4242424242424242" \
   -d "exp_month=11" \
   -d "exp_year=2016" \
   -d "cvc=123" \
   -d "name=Abdullah Mohammed"
```

I am not pretty good with curl URL calling. 
I want to call this URL in android how can I pass header in Android in this example?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a header using a HTTP request through a curl call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call)

Comment: if you find any answer related to the payfort request so let me know thanks in advance