# file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 463

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to get RSS from other sites. They all work fine using `file_get_contents` except one link give me this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://alwatan.kuwait.tt/rss.ashx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 463

I download all files and all have:

```
<rss version="2.0">
```

but the link with error have:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

this is the only difference between them.

Comment: The page is probably checking for bots. Try using curl + header and user agent headers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2570832/1935500

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me that that feed is not allowing you to grab it.

> 463 Restricted Client: This resource is not available for access by your
>   client software. This request has been blocked. Please retry your
>   request from a different client.
>
> DOSarrest Internet Security is a cloud based fully managed DDoS
>   protection service. This request has been blocked by DOSarrest due to
>   the above violation. If you believe you are getting blocked in error
>   please contact the administrator of scripts.local to resolve this issue.

You can test this by trying to use a curl instead of file_get_contents

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://alwatan.kuwait.tt/rss.ashx");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "spider");

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

As Aziz mentioned, if you set the agent and the referred, you can get through.

Comment: I would also mimic the user agent and referral which are the 2 mostly common checked headers.

Comment: Let me give it a try and see if they allow it

Comment: thanks man I try cURL and still not working but when I play around with cURL options I found `CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "spider"` and it solve my problem and everything is fine now

Comment: Cool glad you got it working, please accept the answer if you're happy with it.