# How to set request.env Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, omniauth

I want to make request through curl or other stuff `(Net::HTTP.get)`. How can I set `request.env['omniauth.auth']` when I make request? What is `request.env` in general?

For example, take a look at https://github.com/intridea/omniauth#integrating-omniauth-into-your-application

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    self.current_user = @user
    redirect_to '/'
  end

  protected

  def auth_hash
    request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end
end
```

I don't know how to set request.env['omniauth.auth'] when I do curl

Comment: Normally `request.env` pertains to requests being *received*, not being made.

Comment: I want to make request with params and when my app receive it, request.env['omniauth.auth'] should be equal to those params. My app check request params request.env['omniauth.auth'], but I have no idea how to manage them

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing. Can you include some code that demonstrates what you're attempting?

Comment: Must you use something like curl that's outside Ruby, or can rack-test accomplish this? https://github.com/brynary/rack-test

Comment: Okay, take a look at https://github.com/intridea/omniauth#integrating-omniauth-into-your-application def auth_hash
    request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end I don't know how to set this param when I do curl

Answer (score 0):

You really need stuff for manage ENV global vars. And use it like ENV['omniauth_facebook']

Use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem, and it is good in production too.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP headers should show up in the `request.env` with `HTTP_` prefixed.

With [httpie](https://httpie.io/), this is as simple as

```
http scheme://your-url.tld/path/to/endpoint Header:Something
```

You should be able to access this with `request.env['HTTP_Header']`

Comment: For how to do this with `curl`, checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/356714/393021