# How to get file name during filter in Tomcat Server while sending the file through curl command

Tags: java, http, tomcat, curl, gzip

I am trying to send a csv,png,gzip etc. files into my server . In order to process these files it needs to be filtered based on the proper extension ( csv,png,gzip).

If I can get the filename then I can parse it to get the extension.
This is the way i am sending file:

curl -u user:password -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -T file_name_location -v --noproxy server_name -X POST http://server_name:8080/

I am new to java servlet. I tried printing the httprequest but unable to do so.

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    System.out.println("The http request is " + httpRequest );
```

I cannot send any header except "Tranfer-encoding" in curl command. That is the limitation.
Thanks

Comment: I cannot send any header except "Tranfer-encoding" in curl call. That is the limitation, i forget to mention in the question.

Comment: use -F instead of -T ? for example, curl -F upload=@aaa.png url. Then you can use apache.commons.fileupload to get file name easily

Comment: We need to process the file. How will -F help in that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the file name in the URL as a query parameter, i.e.:

```
http://my-server/some/path?filename=foo.bar
```

...or in a HTTP header. See here: [How to send a header using a HTTP request through a curl call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call?rq=1)

Comment: I cannot send any header except "Tranfer-encoding" in curl call. That is the limitation, i forget to mention in the question.

Comment: Use the first method then - passing the file name as a query parameter in the URL

Comment: That is not working. It is asking for headers for particular file-format. I have to get this done in the code where filter is built.

Comment: Not sure I understand, what component is asking for headers? is that your code?

Comment: Yes thats the code part of filter... Once i will receive the file, then i am trying to print the content of the httprequest.

Comment: Suppose you want to decompress the file then you will use "Content-Encoding=gzip" but I am not allowed to  use this header. I have to get the filename for this.

Comment: So can you get the filename from the url parameter as I suggested?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get the filename.

Comment: There is nothing in the code other than which is given in question.

Comment: I want to get the filename through Servlet request.