# Search query works in browser but error out in curl method

Tags: curl, search, http-status-code-404, walmart-api

The following search query works in any internet browser, like IE, Chrome or Firefox.

http://search.mobile.walmart.com/search?query=bread&store=5461&size=20&offset=0

But, if I use `curl` POST method with parameters:

```
curl -d "query=bread&store=5461&size=20&offset=0" -X POST http://search.mobile.walmart.com/search
```

I got error message:

> "StatusCode:404, "error":"Not Found"

Answer (score 2):

If it works in a browser then it's a `GET` method not a `POST` method.
But if you run it with `GET` like this:
`curl -d "query=bread&store=5461&size=20&offset=0" -X GET http://search.mobile.walmart.com/search` . You'll get the following:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;search&#46;mobile&#46;walmart&#46;com&#47;search" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;2d00a81f&#46;1504771199&#46;d72c55
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Which basically means Walmart does not want you to access its website using anything other then a web browser. 
But you still can try changing the headers to mimic a browser. Also change the `UserAgent` string. Look in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call#answer-356714) answer on how to do it. This might help.

**EDIT**
Actually I've checked it right now and using just 
`curl -X GET "http://search.mobile.walmart.com/search?query=bread&store=5461&size=20&offset=0"`

works fine. You dont need to use `-d` with `GET`. Just add the query string to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing 2 mistakes here, first off, that url does not support POST requests, by the looks of it, it only supports GET requests, so don't do `-X POST`, second, the website does not support having the search parameters in the request body, and -d put the data in the request body, in your example, with the `application/x-www-urlencoded` format. this site only supports having the parameters in the request URL by the looks of it. so do

```
curl 'http://search.mobile.walmart.com/search?query=bread&store=5461&size=20&offset=0'
```

this will issue a GET request, with the parameters in the url, just like the website wants. protip, when debugging curl, add the `-v` parameter, it prints lots of useful debugging info :)