# why can l not connect to Wordpress website hosted on aws via the web?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, e-commerce, offline

The website has been online for the past 4 months on this domain https://www.myhomeetal.com but suddenly gives this error.

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
```

l have pinged the domain name and l get the following 
Request_timed_out
Trying to access the application via filezilla gives the error

```
Could not connect to server.
```

Any help with be apprectiated.

Comment: does the instance that hold the website still on in AWS? could you check on your AWS subscription? when you try `nslookup www.myhomeetal.com` does it return the desired IP?

Comment: log in to aws console  check instances is running

Comment: @IdontDownVote ec2 instance is running fine on aws

Comment: @BagusTesa it returned the desired IP

Comment: so, not the dns then. hmm, the last thing to test is the instance itself..

Comment: @BagusTesa the instance is currently showing running in the ec2 dashboard. how do you suggest l test the ec2 instance.

Comment: could you remote desktop (windows) or ssh (unix variants) to the instance and hit the website from inside?

Comment: @BagusTesa l can ssh into the instance and l can see the wordpress files. but how do hit the website from inside..

Comment: could you check the web server services -- like apache? and its config, try to find the domain and [`curl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call) it - e.g. `curl -X GET localhost --head`, assuming your wordpress is bound on localhost.