# spring security csrf protection not accepting header or cookie (X-XSRF-token)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf-token

I am developing a SPRING rest service with Spring Security and I have enabled the CSRF token like below

```
http
    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).
```

Now, the problem is I need to pass the XSRF token backe to server to complete the authentication, for that I have tried  couple of ways using curl command but no luck, any kind of help would be of great help help. and below are the curl commnads example, i have used and the server response.

```
    curl -i -X POST -d username=user1@gmail.com -d password=user  -c 
    /opt/cookies.txt --header "X-XSRF-TOKEN=18280b55-8fc7-4266-9116- 
    d21df13b841d"  http://localhost:8080/login
```

and this the response from the server

```
HTTP/1.1 401 
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=18280b55-8fc7-4266-9116-d21df13b841d; Path=/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; base-uri 'self';     https://fonts.google.com/; script-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' ; style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' ; connect-src 'self' ; font-src https://fonts.google.com/ ; form-action 'self' ; frame-ancestors 'none' ; img-src 'self' ; media-src 'self' ; object-src 'none' ; plugin-types 'none' ; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'
Referrer-Policy: origin
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 20 May 2019 18:56:10 GMT
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call

Comment: Why do you use `= ` instead of `:`?

Comment: Thanks, let me correct that