# "Copy as cURL" in GET request contains cookie field while i am not logged-in into the site

Tags: linux, curl, cookies, get, header

While checking for GET parameters through the browser request (Network tab of Developer Tools, navigate to the needed page, use "Copy as cURL"), i am getting the "Cookie" field in the curl GET request while i am not logged-in into the site.

I checked the same behavior for stackoverflow site and get the following information ---

**curl '[How to send a header using a HTTP request through a curl call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call)'
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://www.google.com/' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: prov=bb86d13f-93aa-5521-ab14-01f4e8123850; notice-dmb=4%3B1587648961693' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'TE: Trailers'**

My doubt is why i am getting "Cookie" field and what is the significance of this field (for not logged in user).
Also, whether this cookie field value will change for every user request ?

Answer (score 0):

You are geeting this because browser will always look at the http request you made and attaches any unexpired cookies it has for that domain

Comment: So, you mean to say that the cookie browser is sending may be expired too ?
Can i check the age of the cookie by any means ?