# How to send POST request from commandline?

Tags: linux, curl, post

I'm trying to send an "on" signal to a wemo smart plug. I want to send the signal from the linux command line. I know that the request is supposed to look like what I've included below, but I'm not sure what syntax to use. I tried using cURL, but couldn't quite seem to figure it out. Any help would be super appreciated!

```
POST /upnp/control/basicevent1
SOAPACTION: "urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1#SetBinaryState"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: 192.168.1.116:49153
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 306
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:SetBinaryState xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1">
        <BinaryState>0</BinaryState>
        </u:SetBinaryState>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I tried putting each of the headers in quotes after a "-H" but then I wasn't sure what to do with the headers that are already quoted. Also, it appeared to be still sending to port 80 even though I included the host header with a different port?

As far as I know, the plug has an IP address but no web address.

Answer (score 0):

Post method have two part (header & body).
You should run cURL command like that:

## Send Header:

`curl -X POST -H 'SOAPACTION: "urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1#SetBinaryState"' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"' http://192.168.1.116:49153/upnp/control/basicevent1`

With this method, you can head multi header POST.

## Send body POST:

And also with that command you can send POST body:

`curl -X POST -F '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>...' http://192.168.1.116:49153/upnp/control/basicevent1`

Also, they're available at the following links:
[How to send body POST](https://linuxize.com/post/curl-post-request/) ,
[How to send header POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call)

## Command you want at single line:

`curl -X POST -H 'SOAPACTION: "urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1#SetBinaryState"' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Host: 192.168.1.116:49153' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Content-Length: 306' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -F '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">\n    <s:Body>\n        <u:SetBinaryState xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1">\n        <BinaryState>0</BinaryState>\n        </u:SetBinaryState>\n    </s:Body>\n</s:Envelope>' http://192.168.1.116:49153/upnp/control/basicevent1`

## alias

If you think this is a long command, you can set as alias.
For e.g:

`alias myPersonalCommandLS='ls -lthra1d'`